# .then firing before promise is resolved - $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm currently building a web app using the Spotify API and the nodejs wrapper for it... However, when I am using $.getJSON(), the .then is firing before the promise is resolved.
For example, I am trying to change the album artwork displayed on my webpage, after I skip to the next song. However, the artwork is changing first, before the song and so the artwork is always of the previous song... My code is below.

Route in index.js:

```
router.get('/skipToNext', function skipToNext(req, res, next) {
  spotifyApi.skipToNext()
  .then(function(data) {
    res.json(data.body);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong! ", err);
  });
});
```

my function to skip the song:

```
function skipToNext() {
  $.getJSON('/skipToNext')
  .then(function() {
    changeAlbumArt();
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("error! ", err);
  });
};
```

changAlbumArt:

```
function changeAlbumArt() {
  $.getJSON('/currentPlayback')
    .then( function(data) {
      console.log("Change album art: " + data);
      var albumCover = data.item.album.images[0];
      var albumName = data.item.album.name;
      var albumCoverUrl = albumCover["url"];
      console.log("url: " + albumCoverUrl);
      console.log("album name: " + albumName);
      console.log("now playing: " + data);
      $(".container-album-cover").css("background", "url(" + albumCoverUrl + ")");
  });
};
```

Thank you to all that answer!

Comment: `$.getJSON('/skipToNext').then(function()...` why don't you use data coming from API (function arguments are empty)? How does `changeAlbumArt` knows what you've fetched?

Comment: What would the router stop from returning immediatelly agter you call spotify api?

Comment: What does `res.json(data.body)` do exactly?

Comment: $.getJSON('/skipToNext').then(function()... returns no data, I have done it this way as a work around for now... changeAlbumArt has another call to the api that gets the data it needs. I have put that code in above

Comment: It is quite easy to get around with async/await.

Comment: how would I do this with async/await, currently trying but it seems it's not working...

Comment: Is the code correct? You're not returning the promise created from `$.getJSON` neither the promise inside the `.then` callback

Comment: Not showing how song gets changed. The `.then()` won't fire until request completes. Your problem analysis is not correct

Comment: Try something like this `router.get('/skipToNext', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
  let data = await spotifyApi.skipToNext();
  res.json(data.body);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong! ", err);
  };
});`

Comment: You cant return a promise from server to client side, and continue with a `then` there. This would your logic expect, but this is not supporteted by the http flow. Thus you have to keep the server from returning until the underlying request to spotify terminated somehow.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is a jQuery method

jQuery does not use the native Promise (with the then/catch constructor)

jQuery re-implement the concept calling it Deferred.

To wait correctly the getJSON complete event,you have to write your code like so

```
$.getJSON('/currentPlayback')
.done( function(data) {
   // Data arrived
}).fail(function(e,xhr){
   // Error occurred
}).always(function(){
   //always callback
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the route code, and notice the order of execution:

1. Route handler function enters, spotify api call is started.
2. That returns a promise (*I assume*), where you attach a continuation function, and `res` is captured in the closure.
3. **At this point, the route handler function returns peacefully**, as the function has finished handling the request.
4. Sometime later, the api call returns (let's assume successfully)and the promise resolves.
5. `res.json(data.body)` is called, but there is no more context around, thus this will never get to the client.

Your problem is, that nothing stops the route handler function to return prematurely. I am maybe wrong, but there is no decent way to overcome this except to make the ajax call synchronous, which is not a good practice (and maybe not possible at all with the spotify api). Well, at least not before ES2017, which introduced `async/await` construct. From node 7.6 you can rewrite your server code this way:

```
router.get('/skipToNext', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let data = await spotifyApi.skipToNext();
        res.json(data.body);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong! ", err);
    };
});
```

This way your route handler function is suspended until the api call returns. Then the function is resumed. If the promise resolved, you will get the returned data in the `data` variable unwrapped from the promise - if it failed and was rejected, will throw an exception. Now you can feed the `res` variable and let the route handler function return.